# meaning of というように

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, abbreviations

I'm interested in the grammatical function and overall precise translation of the conjunction made of two particles(?) in the following clause. My attempt: "being tall, (as/like/for example/of/that is/such that/as in/reaching/having/hoping?) at least 180cm". Why couldn't we just use a simple の-particle instead?

> ...百八十センチ以上と、背の高いこと...
> と  here  is  an  abbreviation  of  と　いう　よう　に.
> (Read Real Japanese)

I suspect these grammar dictionary entries are relevant:

> ㊦ という Phrase
>
> A phrase marking information which identifies or explains the noun
> following the phrase. Called; that says ~; that
>
> ㊦ ように (2) Auxiliary Adjective (な)
>
> An adverbial
> form of ようだ
> As; like

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific.  These points of grammar are used in a variety of ways.  Without much more context, you're leaving us guessing or just scratching our heads.

Comment: @A.Ellett Here's the whole sentence: 
由美ちゃんは、学歴と収入の高さに 加えて、百八十センチ以上と、背の高いことも、必須条件に加えた。

Comment: I have never thought this と is an "abbreviation". と has a content-descripting function all by itself. の doesn't work because 180cm以上 modifies an adjective ("(背が)高い"). Unfortunately this と doesn't have a perfect equivalent in English, but "like" may be the closest. In written English, parentheses or a colon can be used (`being tall (180 cm or more)`).